# Limit to number of listening ports in linux

Tags: linux, netstat, socket

I have tried to launch a script to listen to thousands of tcp ports (1000 to 10000) but it appears to be hitting a limit of 1024 listening ports. I've confirmed this via netstat and closed ports above certain ranges.

Is there a fixed limit of listening ports in linux and how, if possible, can this be raised?

Comment: what does `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range` tell you?

Comment: Output below
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768 61000

Answer (score 4):

You are probably hitting at nofile limit, which is by default 1024.

Try raising ulimit -n in your shell before running the program, like:

```
$ ulimit -n 20480; ./myprogram
```

Offcourse, you have to have priviledge to raise nofile limit so high, so check current soft and hard limits with:

```
$ ulimit -a
```

And raise them in /etc/security/limits.conf or /etc/security/limits.d/*conf

Comment: I have raised soft and hard nofile limits from 1024/4096 to 16384/32768 but still hitting the 1024 listening ports limit.

Answer (score 0):

By the way I didn't mention that the program/script is launched by xinetd, and that xinetd is ignoring the ulimit nofile settings, looking at the xinetd source now to try and bypass this limitation.